# Is it possible to create a type alias that has trait bounds on a generic type for a function?

Tags: generics, rust, function-pointers, traits, type-alias

This code:

```
pub type Foo<T: Read> = fn(bar: T);
```

yields [error E0122](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.25.0/error-index.html#E0122) (in newer versions of Rust, it is only a warning):

> An attempt was made to add a generic constraint to a type alias. This
>   constraint is entirely ignored. For backwards compatibility, Rust
>   still allows this with a warning. Consider the example below:
>
> ```
> trait Foo {}
>
> type MyType<R: Foo> = (R, ());
>
> fn main() {
>     let t: MyType<u32>;
> }
> ```
>
> We're able to declare a variable of type `MyType<u32>`, despite the fact
>   that `u32` does not implement `Foo`. As a result, one should avoid using
>   generic constraints in concert with type aliases.

Is it possible to create a type alias that contains trait requirements on a function pointer? Obviously the compiler is telling me no for types, but didn't know if there was another option for functions that I wasn't thinking of.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible, as the error says.  Experimenting with `Fn(T)` as well didn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At this time, it does not seem to be possible and no workarounds exist.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone still curious about this as of Rust 1.47.0 it is still not possible but it looks like you get a nice little warning message with a description and suggested alternative.
e.g.

```
pub type PublishQueue<T: From<Message>> = (tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender<T>);
```

yields

```
note: `#[warn(type_alias_bounds)]` on by default
help: the bound will not be checked when the type alias is used, and should be removed
|
| pub type PublishQueue<T> = sync::mpsc::Sender<T>;
|
```